# Put \n (line breaks) in text that is contained by an array variable

Tags: javascript

I have an array which contains text strings at each index. I want to insert a line break at a particular index of the string at particular intervals of the array.

For example, `arr[2]` contains the string `'hello there all how are you people'`. Now I want to insert `\n` at the 11th letter of `arr[2]`, resulting in `'hello there\n all how are you people'`.  Then do the same for `arr[7]`, `arr[12]`, `arr[17]`, and to every 5th index after that.

Comment: Do you want to add \n after each array index string, or after a certain number of characters ?

Comment: Simple logic would be to extract substring like this . first extract "hello there" and store in a string then extract the later of the string  and store in a  different variable. finally concatenate both the strings with '\n'( line break).

Comment: after certain number of characters..

Comment: im getting the string from a html table directly to array, so now different array index have diff strings, and i want to put /n at 11th letter of some index strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, Add a function to string using `prototype`

```
String.prototype.insert = function (index, inputValue) {
    if (index > 0) return this.substring(0, index) + inputValue + this.substring(index, this.length);
    else return inputValue + this;
};
```

Usage

```
var str = "hello there all how are you people";
str = str.insert(11, "\n");
console.log(str);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qTYv2/)

Reference: http://coderamblings.wordpress.com/2012/07/09/insert-a-string-at-a-specific-index/

Answer (score 0):

This is simply a matter of creating a loop to edit each string at `arr[i]` where `i` starts at 2 and increments by 5, and then concatenating the substrings of the string with `\n`.

```
var i,
    len = arr.length;

for (i = 2; i < len; i += 5) {
    arr[i] = arr[i].substr(0, 11) + '\n' + arr[i].substr(11);
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tR86k/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Hey buddy  here is what i have done it for

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wa6UC/1/)

**JS CODE:**

```
var str="hello there all how are you people";
console.log(str);
var divider=11;
var firstHalf=  str.substr(0,divider);
var secondHalf= str.substr(divider);
var finalStr=firstHalf+"\n"+secondHalf;
 console.log(finalStr);
```

Happy Coding :)

**Edited**

Comment: You are replacing, not inserting.

Comment: Does my code say so ? i think its merely inserting the line break after the the specified position mentioned in divider .if you notice carefully i`m just splitting the string in two halves and introducing a line break.

Comment: If you look at it even *more* carefully, you'll see that by ending one substring at the index specified by `divider` and beginning the next substring at the index specified by `divider+1` you are actually replacing the character that was at the index specified by `divider` with a line break. In order to insert the line break instead of replacing a character with it, get rid of the `+1`!